# How to update azure ad b2c custom user attribute using graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm new to the Azure B2C .I created custom attribute extension_role against a user object.i want to update this attribute using graph api.I tried below code

```
public async Task UpdateUsersRole(string id)
        {
         IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            extensionInstance.Add("extension_role", "admin");
            var user = new User
            {
          
                AdditionalData = extensionInstance

            };

            await  GraphClient.Users[id]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(user);
        }
```

is that correct way to update the custom attribute?.While executing i got an error also

> Code: Request_BadRequestMessage: One or more property values specified
> are invalid.Inner error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code changes and also verify whether the user you are trying update has the custom attribute or not.

```cs
public static async Task UpdateCustomAtrributeUserId(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    Console.Write("Enter user object ID: ");
    string userId = Console.ReadLine();
    string CustomAtrribute = "B2C_Custom_AtrributeName";

    Console.WriteLine($"Looking for user with object ID '{userId}'...");

    try
    {
      //Get User details to Verify the existing values
        var result = await graphClient.Users[userId]
          .Request()
          .Select($"id,givenName,surName,displayName,identities,{CustomAtrribute}")
          .GetAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(result);

        if (result != null)
        {
            //Enter the New custom attribute value
            Console.WriteLine("Enter custom attribute value");
            string updatecustomeattribvalue = Console.ReadLine();
            
            //Fill custom attribute value
            IDictionary<string, object> extensionInstance = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            extensionInstance.Add(CustomAtrribute, updatecustomeattribvalue);
            //Updating the custom attribute 
            var updatedresult  = await graphClient.Users[userId]
                    .Request()
                    .UpdateAsync(new User {
                        AdditionalData = extensionInstance
                    });
           
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedresult));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: result is Microsoft.Graph.User. while updating same error occured

Comment: Does the user is having the custom attribute which you are trying to update

Comment: i called users list then it return like the extension_50c0962467e94558913d853598913dsd_role this

Comment: 50c0962467e94558913d853598913dsd this value is application id of b2c-extensions-app. Do not modify. Used by AADB2C for storing user data.

Comment: how do i check this values?

Comment: Please use the same format as extension_guid_custom  while trying to update

Comment: how to get this guid grammatically

Comment: Please use this [helper class](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Helpers/B2cCustomAttributeHelper.cs#L7-L20)