# How to view/edit values from User Claims inside Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I see what claims I have in the **User attributes** blade under **Azure AD B2C** but how can I read these claims for individual users?

For example, if I make a claim EyeColor, is there any way I can read/edit that claim using Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a user attributes/Custom attributes are assigned to a user while Creating/Sign-up.
Using the Graph query/ [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)/ programatically you can get the user details with user attributes using below query.

Get `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/user-id`

[image]

With in the user details you can see the EyeColor value as
***extenstion_b2c-extensions-app_attributeName***

`"extension_f03e52a0a21349eebc05_EyeColor": "black"`

You can update the User attribute with the below query

```
Patch  

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/User-id

Request Body:-

{
    "extension_f03e52a0a21349eebc05_EyeColor": "Brown"
}
```

[image]

Using programatically also you can implement this Please refer this [similar SO quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815710/how-to-update-azure-ad-b2c-custom-user-attribute-using-graph-api)